# LDAP: How to add a person to an existing group?

Tags: ldap, ldif

Using command-line (Linux) or LDIF, I could find many examples of creating a new group and defining its members, but no examples of this:

How to add a user to an existing group?

Let's say the person also already exists.

For instance adding user `uid=fred,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com` to group `cn=vipb,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You add a `memberUid` attribute to the group. For example:

```
$ ldapmodify -D <admin DN> -h <ldaphost>
password: [enter password]
dn: cn=vipb,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: memberUid
memberUid: fred

^D
```

For the record, the LDAP schema is described in [RFC 2307](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2307.txt).

Comment: By the way, I recommend using a point-and-click LDAP browser to get a feel for your LDAP structure and schema. Back in the day I used [JXplorer](http://jxplorer.org/) but there may be better ones these days.

Comment: [Apache Directory Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) is a good alternative.